# Docker Compose Nextcloud privileges error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, mariadb, nextcloud

I´m trying to install on Raspberry Pi 4 a Nextcloud Docker following the next tutorial:
https://www.addictedtotech.net/installing-nextcloud-on-raspberry-pi-4/

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: yobasystems/alpine-mariadb:latest
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /media/pi/Elements/nextclouddb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=YOURROOTPASSWORD
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=YOURPASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - UID=1000
      - GID=1000
  app:
    image: nextcloud
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - /media/pi/Elements/nextcloud:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - UID=1000
      - GID=1000
    restart: always
```

[image]

After launch the stack, it appears an Interface error:

```
You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe.
```

I've checked the directories and where Nextcloud should is empty, so I think it could be a privileges thing, but the UID and GID are the 'pi' user number:

[image]

What can I try next?

**Update:** TI've tried to create the DB in the internal drive and I see that the Database is created (or updated?) by *systemd-timesyncd* user, which I don't know why appears. Maybe because the bridge between two containers?

Thanks again

Comment: So when you use;

sudo chmod 777  /list the directory

It doesn't work?

Comment: I can't @EmmanuelSpencerEgbuniwe because nextcloud requires restricted privileges to their folders :-(

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the user `pi` to the `docker` group? To do so : `sudo usermod -aG docker pi`.
Then confirm with the `groups` command to check that `pi` is a member of the `docker` group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes it is. I've tried to created the DB in the internal drive and I see that the Database is created  (or updated?) by systemd-timesyncd user, which I don't know why appears (maybe because the bridge between two containers?)